# SSIS / Excel - Selected Index Cell offset by +1

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I am using ssis 2010 and my excel is my destination

as you know excel index starts as 0

I have sql command as

```
SELECT * FROM [Data$E27:P27]
```

as when inserting data you always have to do row -1 as really my data is should be

```
SELECT * FROM [Data$E28:P28]
```

but the row it sees because index starts as 0 , is a date row... error is obviously saying cannot insert text into a date, is there a way that you can start the excel index on 1 so I can use

```
 SELECT * FROM [Data$E28:P28]
```

please help

Comment: What do you mean, the top row is a "date" row? Perhaps the problem is that you don't have headers, but you have your data source configured as the data *has* headers (or the reverse)? If you need to import columns E-P in row 28, then `SELECT * FROM [Data$E28:P28]` is the current statement. That will import the values from cells `E28`, `F28`, `G28`,..., `O28` and `P28`, and only those cells.

Comment: it does not work like that as index always on 0 , please help, hence why I have to say 27, instead of 28 to put my data on that row. , issue I have is ssis ironically sees that row 27 is a date formatted row , and then complains

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work like that"? It does. How I describe is **exactly** how it works. That functionality hasn't changed since SSIS 2008 (can't say for 2005, as I didn't use it).

Comment: the row of data should go onto 28, but because the way indexing works on excel, you have to put 27...issue I have is ironically , when I put this in row 27 is a date formatted column. it sees that, even though the data will land on 28